# Where's the security issue in my file

Tags: php

Each time i upload this image viewer to my website i get hacked, i.e. someone hack my website any change passwords each time i upload this. the hacker always upload php shells. but there's no way to upload file.

```
include "./config.php";

@ $db = mysql_pconnect($mysql['host'], $mysql['user'], $mysql['pass']) or die(mysql_error());

if ($_GET['id'])
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}
else
{
    header( 'Location: http://404.html' ) ;
    exit;
}

$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id, $db);

//IT"S NOT WORKING!
if (!$db)
{
    die("error");
}
mysql_select_db($mysql['db']) or die(mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE id='" . $id . "'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if (!$result)
{
    die("MySQL Select error");
}

$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_results ==0)
{
header( 'Location: http:///404.html' );
exit;
}
else{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $downloads = $row['downloads'] + 1;

    $lastuse = time();

     $ss = mysql_query("select downloads from `images` where id='".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
     $rr = mysql_fetch_array($ss);

    $query = "update `images` set downloads=downloads+1, lastuse='" . $lastuse . "' where id='".$id."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result)
    {
        die("MySQL update error");
    }


    //get current stats
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `stat_cache` WHERE 1";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result)
    {
        die("MySQL Select error");
    }
    $stat = mysql_fetch_array($result);


    //downloads update
    $downloads = $stat['downloads'] + 1;
    $query = "UPDATE `stat_cache` SET downloads='" . $downloads . "' WHERE 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result)
    {
        die("MySQL Update error");
    }
}
//Lets create the image, now.
if(!file_exists('./images/' . $id)) {
header( 'Location: http:///404.html' ) ;
    exit;
}
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$fp = fopen('./images/' . $id, 'r');

$contents = fread($fp, $maxfilesize);
fclose($fp);

echo $contents;
```

can any one please tells me where is the security issue here ?

Comment: what you want to know exactly? sql injection?

Comment: Obligatory Bobby Tables: http://xkcd.com/327/ And look up SQL injection and php prepared statements

Comment: i get hacked = someone hack my website any change passwords each time i upload this, ok Levi Morrison how do i avoid this ? how do i fix it ?

Comment: @Alamri, if the id is an int, use an int. `("... WHERE id=".(int)$id);`

Comment: @popnoodles Unfortunately it contain both numbers and characters.

Comment: Could the vulnerability lie in the included `config.php` file, perhaps?

Comment: It could be in config but OP has said it happens when this is uploaded. Where did this file come from and how are people using it normally?

Comment: @popnoodles I agree, it was just conjecture because I don't see anything here :/

Comment: I'm with you, looking at the include is the next step I'd take too.

Comment: @Alamri, this is not advised but if you can't find the solution to this and you're prepared to upload the file once more, after backing up everything, write a function that will log or email you every $_GET, $_POST and every SQL that's executed. Then sit and wait and the  hacker will show you how they are doing it.

Comment: @popnoodles you want me to include config.php ? it only have database details also site name to be set in page title, and this script used to view images. like this `img.php?id=iuwsY`. using the geven id it get the image from /images to show it with headers set.

Comment: do you allow user to upload images? or files?

Comment: Probably no need for config. @Akam has a point, there might be a bigger picture that you haven't told us about, it's really quite important that you do.

Comment: @Akam yes but throw very secured api using mobile application with high Java security i made my self, no one is able to upload any fake image, no one is able to upload without using a security key. even from server side the php will not allow uploading fake images

Comment: @Akam i launched the application yesterday and i checked every image that uploaded, all seems clear.

Comment: The only way then: the hacker uploaded fake image containing shel script and then including that image through this file (the code that you posted), the hacker might be your neighbor- (using same server)

Comment: @Akam i own the server only 1 website mine, this kidde is getting me nervus, each time i upload this file i get hacked. also i'm pretty sure no one can upload fake image

Comment: Check the webserver logs - you might find some interesting data (unusual user agents, blind scan, unusually aggressive requests, etc.) there.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101993/can-a-php-shell-be-injected-into-an-image-how-would-this-work

Comment: Ok, how you upload that file? using FTP? what are file and folder permissions? I am also confused...

Comment: @DCoder i did and find his IP in logs, but some how i can't see what he do !! he always clean logs i don't know how he do that.i can only see his IP without seeing the files he browse or even the time. i only see like this `IPADRESS 00:00:00 00-00-0000 200`

Comment: @DavidEugenePeterson thank you i will look after that.

Comment: can you download all images and check them? use notepad++ and search for <? or <?php

Comment: @Akam i use Cpanel and files are 644 folders 755.

Comment: @Akam yes i did they are 2500 files. only 1 day, website traffic is high.

Comment: add this line to the end before echo $contents;
$contents = str_replace(array("<?php", "<?", "?>"), "", $contents);

Comment: @Akam even if the header set to image/jpg you think he can browse the image as a php ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24257/discussion-between-akam-and-alamri)

Comment: @DavidEugenePeterson can you please give me an example of the fake tiff image ? i need to test it, it my slove the whole thing.

Comment: Here's a png that activates when 32px/32px
http://www.idontplaydarts.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/resized-256x256.png

Comment: @DavidEugenePeterson can i test it ? or do i have to resize it then test it ?

Comment: I've expanded my answer and provided the proper link pertaining to that image. "Resize to 32x32 using imagecopyresample and save as a PNG using GD to reveal the shell."

Comment: Maybe you should also post your file upload script.

Comment: This might be stating the obvious, but make sure you block people from directly accessing `http://yoursite.com/images/iuwsY` via their browser (without going through your script).

Comment: @DCoder i did deny everyone using htaccess. `order deny, allow
deny from all `